# Error 1321 in INF when compiling Windows Driver KMDF

Tags: windows, driver, isolation, inf

It's been a long time I haven't developed drivers on Windows, that dates back to Windows XP.

At the time, I had done one based on DiskPerf.

Fast forward to today, and I'd like to develop a driver for Windows 10/11. Diskperf again seems like a nice place to start, I had to download it from the WDK 8.0.

I started updating the project, and I'm now stuck on this:
"diskperf.inf(33-33): error 1321: Registry root (HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}) of value 'UpperFilters' is not isolated to HKR."

Corresponding lines of the inf file are:

```
[diskperf.AddReg]
HKLM, System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}, UpperFilters, 0x00010008, diskperf.
```

I've been reading, and I can't understand how to change it. I downloaded the sources of an open source project, VeraCrypt, which has a filter driver. The inf reads very similarly:

```
[veracrypt.AddReg]
HKLM, System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}, UpperFilters, 0x00010008, veracrypt
```

I don't know how to fix that issue (or how to rewrite things so that it gets loaded as a filter driver on disk drives).

Here's the complete inf:

```
; diskperf.inf
;
; Installation inf for the Disk Performance Monitor Filter driver [ DDK Sample ]
;
; Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
;

[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"
Class     = DiskDrive
ClassGUID = {4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Provider  = %lpc%
DriverVer = 03/22/2002,5.1.2600.0
CatalogFile=diskperf.cat
PnpLockdown=1

;
; General installation section
;

[DefaultInstall.NTx86]
CopyFiles = @diskperf.sys
Addreg    = diskperf.AddReg

[DefaultInstall.ntamd64]
CopyFiles = @diskperf.sys
Addreg    = diskperf.AddReg


[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir = 13

[diskperf.AddReg]
;https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-addreg-directive
;https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/registry-trees-and-keys
;https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/run-from-driver-store

HKLM, System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}, UpperFilters, 0x00010008, diskperf.
;HKR,{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318},UpperFilters,0x10000,diskperf



;
; Service installation section
;

[DefaultInstall.NTx86.Services]
AddService = diskperf, , diskperf.Service.Install

[DefaultInstall.NTamd64.Services]
AddService = diskperf, , diskperf.Service.Install

[diskperf.Service.Install]
DisplayName    = %service_desc%
ServiceType    = 1
StartType      = 0
ErrorControl   = 1
ServiceBinary  = %13%\diskperf.sys
LoadOrderGroup = "PnP Filter"

[SourceDisksFiles]
diskperf.sys=1

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %diskid1%,,,

;
; Localizable Strings
;

[Strings]

service_desc = "Disk Performance Monitor Filter Driver"
diskid1      = "Microsoft Corp. Installation Disk #1 (DiskPerf)"
lpc          = "company"
```

Comment: I do not have an answer to the question, however, I followed the "Getting started" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver), and slowly introduced things from my older driver. When it came to the upper filter line in .inf it just worked.